# How to apply two different styles in View component in React native

Tags: react-native

I am working on a React native project, I am trying to apply two different styles in View Component but it is taking only one style someone please tell me how to overcome this issue

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const App = props => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}} style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Mark</Text>
      <Text>Williams</Text>
      <Text>Henry</Text>
      <Text>Tom</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 0,
    padding: 20,
    color: '#ff0000',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try like below,

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const App = props => {
  return (
    <View style={[{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}, styles.container]}>
      <Text>Mark</Text>
      <Text>Williams</Text>
      <Text>Henry</Text>
      <Text>Tom</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 0,
    padding: 20,
    color: '#ff0000',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Using a style array you can set multiple styles for a same component.